# Get String between 2 Strings or delimeters in bash using regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell

My String is:

```
model_config_list: {
   config: {
       name: "123-model",
       base_path: "/modelServers/tests-integration/resources/models/123-model",
       model_platform: "tensorflow",
       model_version_policy: {
           all: {}
       }
   }
```

I want to extract:

```
/modelServers/tests-integration/resources/models/123-model
```

for that I wrote bash script :

```
config_file=$(<conf.conf)
regex="(?<=base_path:)(.*)(?=,)"
if [[ $config_file =~ $regex ]];then echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; fi
```

However, I am not getting any output. I am a beginner with Bash scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a regex with a capturing group rather than lookarounds that are not supported in Bash regex:

```
regex='base_path:[[:space:]]*"([^"]+)"'
if [[ $config_file =~ $regex ]];then 
  echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
fi
```

Output:

```
/modelServers/tests-integration/resources/models/123-model
```

See the [**Bash demo online**](http://rextester.com/DJB86281).

**Details**

The positive `(?<=base_path:)` lookbehind and `(?=,)` lookahead are not supported in Bash regex. The point here is to match `base_path:` with any whitespace after it, then `"`, and then capture into Group 1 any one or more chars other than `"` (using a negated bracket expression `[^"]+`).

- `base_path:` - a literal substring
- `[[:space:]]*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `"` - a double quote
- `([^"]+)` - 1 or more chars other than a `"` char
- `"` - a double quote.

Answer (score 2):

Bash doesn't support lookaround assertions. But you don't need them:

```
regex='base_path: "([^"]*)"'
```